# Keyboard shortcuts for 3D views in autocad?

Tags: autocad

I'm considering a switch to AutoCad from TurboCad and I'm trying a trial of AutoCad 2014 for Mac.  I feel stupid for having to ask this, but googling hasn't turned up any answers and keyboard shortcut lists don't seem to include commands for toggling 3D view to Top, Bottom, Left, Right, Front, Back.  Closest I've found is by typing "View" then clicking a view from the drop down .  Every CAD app and 3D app I've ever used had them, surely shortcuts are there somewhere, right?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The shortcuts available out-of-the-box vary depending on the flavor of AutoCAD and the active workspace, but I don't believe plain vanilla AutoCAD defines view shortcuts out-of-the-box. There are several different ways to define keyboard shortcuts in AutoCAD. You could use the CUI command to define shortcuts in your menu file. I'm not very familiar with the Mac version, but on Windows I would create a file named acaddoc.lsp in the AutoCAD support path and there define lisp based shortcuts, something like (to define a VT command):

```
(defun C:VT () (command "_-VIEW" "Top"))
```